# Анимация загруженности приложения

Tags: c#, анимация, wpf

Здравствуйте, как мне создать анимацию загруженности приложения, например, чтобы работала определённая  анимация (к примеру крутящийся кружок или мигающая надпись= загрузка)

т.е. как мне единоразово написать анимацию и подключать её к разным элементам, например напротив грида с данными что бы была эта анимация (т.е. не писать анимацию для каждого элемента)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что писать с нуля ничего не стоит, посмотрите вот этот компонент: [BusyIndicator](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator). Его можно вешать на любой контрол.